# On my drop down menu I don't want the whole extension to change on the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I'm making a language drop down menu for my website. It works perfectly fine as you can see but the issue I am having is that I do not want index.html to be replaced once I select a different language. So if you save the HTML & JQuery, what happens when you first load up the toolbar is

**C:/Users/[your name]/Desktop/Drop_Down/index.html**

But if I switch the language to French for example that "index.html" disappears and will turn into

**C:/Users/[your name]/Desktop/Drop_Down/&locale=fr_FR**

What my goal is trying to aim for is not having that index.html disappear, e.g.

**C:/Users/[your name]/Desktop/Drop_Down/index.html&locale=fr_FR**

If anyone can help me that'll be wonderful, I'm just learning how to do this by self teaching myself. Thanks everyone! (I also have css code but I didn't include it because it's a style sheet and doesn't affect the function of the website)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // --- language dropdown --- //

  // turn select into dl
  createDropDown();

  var $dropTrigger = $(".dropdown dt a");
  var $languageList = $(".dropdown dd ul");

  // open and close list when button is clicked
  $dropTrigger.toggle(function() {
    $languageList.slideDown(200);
    $dropTrigger.addClass("active");
  }, function() {
    $languageList.slideUp(200);
    $(this).removeAttr("class");
  });

  // close list when anywhere else on the screen is clicked
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
      $languageList.slideUp(200);
    $dropTrigger.removeAttr("class");
  });

  // when a language is clicked, make the selection and then hide the list
  $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
    var clickedValue = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    var clickedTitle = $(this).find("em").html();
    $("#target dt").removeClass().addClass(clickedValue);
    $("#target dt em").html(clickedTitle);
    $languageList.hide();
    $dropTrigger.removeAttr("class");
  });
});

// actual function to transform select to definition list
function createDropDown(){
  var $form = $("div#country-select form");
  $form.hide();
  var source = $("#country-options");
  source.removeAttr("autocomplete");
  var selected = source.find("option:selected");
  var options = $("option", source);
  $("#country-select").append('<dl id="target" class="dropdown"></dl>')
  $("#target").append('<dt class="' + selected.val() + '"><a href="#"><span class="flag"></span><em>' + selected.text() + '</em></a></dt>')
  $("#target").append('<dd><ul></ul></dd>')
  options.each(function(){
    $("#target dd ul").append('<li class="' + $(this).val() + '"><a href="' + $(this).attr("title") + '"><span class="flag"></span><em>' + $(this).text() + '</em></a></li>');
  });
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Website toolbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="languageswitcher.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="country-select">
        <form action="server-side-script.php">
          <select id="country-options" name="country-options">
            <option selected="selected" title="&locale=en_US" value="us">English(US)</option>
            <option title="&locale=en_GB" value="gb">English(UK)</option>
            <option title="&locale=bg_BG" value="bg">Bulgarian</option>
            <option title="&locale=cs_CS" value="cs">Czech</option>
            <option title="&locale=da_DK" value="dk">Danish</option>
            <option title="&locale=de_DE" value="de">German</option>
            <option title="&locale=ek_GR" value="gr">Greek</option>
            <option title="&locale=es_ES" value="es">Spanish</option>
            <option title="&locale=et_ET" value="et">Estonian</option>
            <option title="&locale=fi_FI" value="fi">Finnish</option>
            <option title="&locale=fr_FR" value="fr">French</option>
            <option title="&locale=hu_HU" value="hu">Hungarian</option>
            <option title="&locale=it_IT" value="it">Italian</option>
            <option title="&locale=lt_LT" value="lt">Lithuanian</option>
            <option title="&locale=lv_LV" value="lv">Latvian</option>
            <option title="&locale=nl_NL" value="nl">Dutch</option>
            <option title="&locale=no_NO" value="no">Norwegian</option>
            <option title="&locale=pl_PL" value="pl">Polish</option>
            <option title="&locale=pt_PT" value="pt">Portugese</option>
            <option title="&locale=ro_RO" value="ro">Romanian</option>
            <option title="&locale=sk_SK" value="sk">Slovak</option>
            <option title="&locale=sl_SL" value="sl">Slovenian</option>
            <option title="&locale=sv_SE" value="se">Swedish</option>
          </select>
          <input value="Select" type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
    <script src="jquery_1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="languageswitcher.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the relevant contents of `server_side_script.php`

Comment: @WesFoster I actually don't even have that at all it was just there sorry I forgot to delete, if that's the issue then I thank you but I'm not even using a that php file to test this drop down menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `&locale=sl_SL` to `?locale=sl_SL`

replace all `&` with `?` or make it `index.html?locale=sv_SE`

Essentially, a query string should start with a question mark and not an ampersand.

Comment: That worked! but now when I switch to a country the drop down will redirect it back to English(US) [The default], When I want it to stay on the country.

Comment: For example I switch it to France and it will switch the link but it will redirect the drop down menu right back to English(US)

Comment: That is actually a different problem. Now that the language is properly being passed to the page, you will need to check the query string and select the option as selected. This can be done server side or client side.